# Ignore unset variable error in PHP strict

Tags: php

I'm programming a add/edit form on my local dev machine which is in strict mode. Depending on how the user reaches this form they may or may not have an array set contains form information. Problem is that if I fill in the inputs using `<?= $array['name'] ?>` and they don't have it set every input gets an error. I'd like to just do something quick and simple, since there are a lot of inputs across several pages. Previously I've used `<?= @$array['name'] ?>` but am hoping for a better solution, once that doesn't require me to type `<?= (isset($array['name'])?$array['name']:'') ?>` out for every input (imagine the possibility for typos).

I'd like to keep the undefined message on, because it is useful elsewhere, it's only on specific variables (specifically a single array on the page) that I don't want the message to display. Google hasn't come up with a good solution, most answers being to change error reporting level.

Comment: At the top of your script, just create an array with all the values you will need, set them to an empty string, and overwrite those entries in it that you have actually received data for. So no need to suppress warning/notices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like this to provide "empty defaults" for all array elements:

```
if (empty($array)) {
    $array = array_fill_keys(array('name', 'age', 'address', '...'), null);
}
```

You just need to use it once, at the top of the script.

If there is the possibility of arriving at the page with only *some* of the keys set (in which case you don't want to overwrite the values of the others) you can use this:

```
if (empty($array)) {
    $array = []; // PHP 5.4 syntax
}

$array += array_fill_keys(['name', 'age', 'address', '...'], null);
```

The [array addition operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) is very useful when you want to provide default values but not mess with those that are already present.

Comment: I was initially agains this because I didn't want to have to edit this dummy array if I added a new cell (I know I'd forget to do it and cause all sorts of issues). But this in conjunction with pulling a results and emptying the array will work. Thanks for the idea. Assuming some magic function doesn't solve this more efficiently I'll approve this tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set `error_reporting()` to a level that doesn't throw an exception about these things.

This should be a one-liner. :)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: error_reporting should only be used for diagnosing where to improve your code, not for reporting errors to the end user. error_reporting should be switched off for production environments for security.